# Bind a css selector with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

When the viewmodel is bound to the html I want that the first div inside "replies" gets a certain look (css class) WHEN its isMissing value is true.

How will the binding look like?

```
function ReplayViewModel(value,isMissing) {
 this.value= value;
 this.isMissing = isMissing;
}

<div id="replies">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>

.specialLook{
   background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) is what you are looking for:

```
<div id="replies">
   <div data-bind="css: {specialLook: isMissing}"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XdQSd/)

Comment: So I do not fumble around with the first-child selector right? Its only a knockout issue how to handle special formattings in the ui?

Comment: @Pascal the css binding is the KO way. You can also use it even if you generate the div dynamically with a foreach binding because you can use then the `$index` variable to mark the first item: http://jsfiddle.net/XdQSd/1/

Comment: Thanks the isMissing without index check was enough as I inserted a special viewmodel at the first position always and only this viewmodel has isMissing set = true :)